# jQuery trazer valor da tabela Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estou montando um cadastro de listas de musicas para um site de karaoke. Ele funciona assim:

Busca a música pré-cadastrada
Pega essa música do input e insere em uma lista li

tenho o seguinte:

```
<input id="musica" type="text">
<button type="button" id="add">Adicionar</button>
<ul id="listademusicas">
</ul>

<script>
jQuery('#add').click(function() {
jQuery('#listademusicas').append('<li id="">'+jQuery('#musica').val()+'</li>');
});
</script>
```

Aí eu queria que ao inserir o li, ele trouxesse o id da musica, a tabela está assim:

```
tabela_musicas
id|nome
1 |nome da musica1
2 |nome da musica2
```

No input que pega o nome da música estou usando uma consulta que traz o nome exato da música, então pensei em fazer alguma coisa como

```
SELECT id FROM tabela_musicas WHERE nome = "nome da musica".
```

Mas não sei como fazer essa consulta de forma dinâmica. Eu queria que o id da música fosse inserido no name ou id de cada linha.

Comment: Não seria melhor consultar o banco pelo ID da música em vez de pelo nome?

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso dinamicamente você vai precisar usar o Ajax.

Crie um arquivo/rota que faça a inserção e retorne o que foi inserido.

```
jQuery.post('linkparacadastrarMusica', {nome: nomedaNovaMusica}).done(function(data){
   console.log(data)
})
```

Com isso, você pega o retorno do novo e manipula na sua pagina como quiser.

[Leia mais sobre isso aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Para MySQL, você pode fazer um select assim:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Ela vai retornar o último ID inserido. Isto funciona para aplicações com baixo indice de inserção. Se a aplicação é muito usada, dois insert realizados ao mesmo poerão ter o mesmo ID retornado.

Buscar por nome não é uma boa, porque exigiria que todas as músicas tivessem nomes diferentes.